# Angular tabs form validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have the following structure

```
            <div id="contractTab" class="ui top attached large tabular menu">
            <a id="main-tab" class="item active" data-tab="first" ng-show="ctrl.currentTabsGroup == 'main'">some data</a>
            <a id="supplier-tab" class="item" data-tab="third" ng-show="ctrl.currentTabsGroup == 'supplier'">some data2</a>
            <a id="position-tab" class="item" data-tab="fourth" ng-show="ctrl.currentTabsGroup == 'position'">some data3</a>
            <a class="item" data-tab="second" ng-show="ctrl.currentTabsGroup == 'main'">some data4</a>
            </div>
```

And each tab looks like

```
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="third">
            <div class="ui basic segment">
                <ng-form name="supplierForm">
                ...
                </ng-form>
           </div>
</div>
```

I have many fields required in each form. The problem is that when I try to validate form when this form is active(on screen), I get that it is invalid. For, example

```
supplierForm.$valid == false
```

However, if I move to different form everything apparently erases and I get

```
supplierForm.$valid == true
```

Is there a way to connect all of this forms in order not to lose data?

This function is called when I change tabs

```
resetFormObject(formName);
$s[formName].$setPristine();

$timeout(function() {
     document.getElementById(tabId).click();
}, 20);
```

Where resetFormObject just initializes active object to send it when the form is submitted

Comment: is this multistep form? And are you using ng-if to swtich between tabs?

Comment: @KeyurShah, no it isn't. I have a page and it contains several buttons. So whenever, a button gets clicked program invokes function to change tab. The function is simple document.getElementById(id).click() with some processing.

Comment: ok, Just check while changing tab if it removes the elements of active(on screen) from the DOM and replace with new tab's elements?

Comment: @KeyurShah, I can access form through document.getElementByName("supplierForm"), however I get empty object when I access inner elements of this form when I change tabs. So, yes, probably it removes elements from DOM

Comment: That's the problem. After you change tab elements are removed. and when you switch back to tab it recreates elements again. So all you validation is lost. can you add your function which does the changing of tabs?

Comment: @KeyurShah, I edited my question. Now it contains this function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121915/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-rustam-ibragimov).

Comment: This behaviour is inherent in Angular validation because the rules are defined AND enforced in the view. I.e. *no view* (e.g. removed with `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, tabs etc) -> *no validation*. This is a serious limitation of Angular validation IMO. I am using programmatic/model validation with [egkyron](https://github.com/nikospara/egkyron).